# What does dis=NONE mean in an email's Authentication-Results header?

Tags: smtp, authentication, spf, dkim, dmarc

The following is from an email I received recently:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral;
       dkim=pass header.i=@yahoo.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=yahoo.com
```

I've been reading about SPF, DKIM, and DMARC, but I haven't found any explanation of what dis=NONE means. "dis" isn't listed in the [DMARC tag registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dmarc-parameters/dmarc-parameters.xhtml), so where is it defined and what does it mean?

Comment: Another possible value is `QUARANTINE` and the [FAQ](https://dmarc.org/wiki/FAQ) mentions `disposition`, so it could be the "action" to be performed. However, found no reliable evidence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> dis=none (disposition=none) -- means that Gmail applied "none" policy

http://lists.dmarc.org/pipermail/dmarc-discuss/2013-April/001848.html

Comment: It seems that `dis=none` logically means `result=accepted` but it's just spelled weird.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=DMARC&oldid=906081654) currently explains this very well:

--

The disposition reflects the policy published actually applied to the messages, none, quarantine, or reject. Along with it, not shown in the table, DMARC provides for a policy override. Some reasons why a receiver can apply a policy different from the one requested are already provided for by the specification:

- forwarded: while keeping the same bounce address, usually doesn't break DKIM,
- sampled out: because a sender can choose to only apply the policy to a percentage of messages only,
- trusted forwarder: the message arrived from a locally known source
- mailing list: the receiver heuristically determined that the message arrived from a mailing list,
- local policy: receivers are obviously free to apply the policy they like, it is just cool to let senders know,
- other: if none of the above applies, a comment field allows to say more.

--

For more detail see [RFC 7489](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489).